# Rename a file based on release

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to rename a file when a new release is tagged, but it is failing.

```
    - name: rename file
      run: mv ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/firmware.hex ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/megadesk-${{ $GITHUB_REF_NAME }}.hex
```

However when it runs I get an error

```
Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/version_pio_build.yml#L44
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/version_pio_build.yml (Line: 44, Col: 12): Unexpected symbol: '$GITHUB_REF_NAME'. Located at position 1 within expression: $GITHUB_REF_NAME
```

If I change this to

```
    - name: rename file
      run: mv ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/firmware.hex ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/megadesk-${{ env.GITHUB_REF_NAME }}.hex
```

Then the resulting execution is
`mv ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/firmware.hex ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/megadesk-.hex`

Note this is triggered on a tag push.

```
    - name: env list
      run: env
```

This has a list of variables including

```
...
RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE=/opt/hostedtoolcache
ImageVersion=20220220.1
DOTNET_NOLOGO=1
GITHUB_REF_NAME=v25
GRAALVM_11_ROOT=/usr/local/graalvm/graalvm-ce-java11-22.0.0.2
GITHUB_JOB=build
AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR=/opt/az/azcliextensions
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you used the wrong syntax.

Neither `${{ $GITHUB_REF_NAME }}` nor `${{ env.GITHUB_REF_NAME }}` will work, but just `$GITHUB_REF_NAME` will.

Therefore, your command line should be:

```yaml
run: mv ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/firmware.hex ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/megadesk-$GITHUB_REF_NAME.hex
```

If you want to take a look, here is a demo:

Workflow file: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/49-rename-on-release.yml

Workflow run: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5359686796?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: This did not seem to work for me.

```
Run mv ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/firmware.hex ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/megadesk-$GITHUB_REF_NAME.hex
  mv ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/firmware.hex ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/megadesk-$GITHUB_REF_NAME.hex
```

Comment: Perhaps it is working, but I am then trying to add that newly-named file to a release. Apologies for stackoverflow's terrible comment system.

    - name: Release
      uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
      if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
      with:
        files: ./Code/.pio/build/attiny841/megadesk-$GITHUB_REF_NAME.hex

Comment: I made it work by using the `$GITHUB_ENV` to store the `FILENAME` (with full path)  into an env variable. Because the `$GITHUB_REF_NAME` can only be used inside a command or shell script; not directly as an input to an action. Here is the workflow run: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5363370835?check_suite_focus=true The updated workflow YAML file can still be found here: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/49-rename-on-release.yml

Comment: Great workaround! It works! :)